# Big table in mysql Updating rows based on csv every time

Tags: python, mysql, csv, data-science

I have table with half-million rows and I assume I get CSV file every hour I need to update my MySQL table based on CSV. it might contain new rows or some rows might get modified. The table has a primary key ( named SKU )

Product table columns :

1. SKU
2. Product details
3. Price

I want to do this as fast as possible and One condition is that I can't delete table and load again because "Support for regular non-blocking parallel ingestion of the given file into a table" is my main requirement.

I can use scripting languages like Python.

I have a solution that is to create a temporary table and import data into table and then update my main table.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated

Comment: ETL Tools like Informatica or Talend might solve your problem.

Comment: If architecture is not a constraint and if you might keep data in Elasticsearch instead of MySQL, this can be easily achieved using Logstash and Elastic.

Answer (score 1):

If the new data is an entire set, do the following:

1. `CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;`
2. `LOAD DATA INFILE INTO new ...`  This is the only slow step, but it is not impacting the `real` table.
3. If you need to cleanse the data, do it in this step.  Else, you don't need Python.
4. `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;`  This step is fast.
5. `DROP TABLE old;`

If the incoming data does not contain all the SKUs, then see the techniques here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table